# Tensorflow GPU Check failed: stream‑>parent()‑>GetConvolveAlgorithms

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train my CNN model using Keras with Tensorflow backend.

The problem is, when I run the fit_generator() function, the Python kernel in Spyder crashes. To add a little bit of context, I just installed CUDA and tensorflow-gpu as described in this [link](http://blog.nitishmutha.com/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html) so that I could use my GPU. Prior to this, everything was just fine.

Here is the full log

**An error ocurred while starting the kernel**

```
2018 20:44:44.791399: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018 20:44:45.084153: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.493
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.30GiB
2018 20:44:45.086132: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018 20:44:45.906189: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 3033 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018 20:47:25.845646: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018 20:47:25.846108: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 74 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018 20:47:26.499846: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018 20:47:26.500247: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:389] error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2018 20:47:26.500717: F C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream‑>parent()‑>GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms) 
2018 20:52:22.359428: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018 20:52:22.359982: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:389] error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2018 20:52:22.360678: F C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel‑win\M\windows‑gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream‑>parent()‑>GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)
```

Has anyone ever faced this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem and found a [solution in a Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6698#issuecomment-364702793). You need to update your GPU drivers *after* installing CUDA 9.0, as it seems the installer is reverting you to old drivers. They also suggest rebooting, but in my case that was not necessary.

Comment: Updating drivers with which method exactly? .run file or .deb package?

Comment: I used the deb package

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error installing TF 1.7 on Linux with Python 3.6 via

`conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.7 -c free -y`.

For some reason, during one of the runs I got not only the error message

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:712] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

but also

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:396] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7103 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7005 (compatibility version 7000).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
```

right before it. So, based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960132/cudnn-library-compatibility-error-after-loading-model-weights), I ran

`conda install cudnn==7.0.5`

to change the version of `cudnn` installed automatically along with `tensorflow-gpu==1.7`, and now it works. However, it still takes a lot of time before the training starts.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR) Upgrade your CUDA/CUDNN installation.

CUDA/CUDNN version requirements for TensorFlow may change as new releases ships, and it is very likely that your CUDA/CUDNN version is not compatible. This can happen because of either CUDA and CUDNN version.

Here is the table of TF version and CUDA/CUDNN version compatibility: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu