# Tensorflow-gpu Check Failed:

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, conv-neural-network, nvidia

I followed [tensorflow-gpu installation tutorial](https://github.com/markjay4k/How-To-Install-TensorFlow-GPU/blob/master/Install%20TensorFlow%201.5.ipynb) and it seems to have installed fine according to the example on tensorflow website. But I am getting a

`Check failed:  stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)`

error. I saw a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132736/tensorflow-gpu-check-failed-stream-parent-getconvolvealgorithms) that worked for someone else having the same error by updating the gpu drivers and rebooting it, but mine doesn't seem to work.

Here's the complete error:

```
$py cnn_train.py
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
cnn_train.py:21: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 200,..., activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(200, 200, 1), activation='relu'))
cnn_train.py:24: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 200,..., activation="relu")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(200, 200, 1), activation='relu'))
cnn_train.py:33: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg..., units=150)`
  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
cnn_train.py:38: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg..., units=150)`
  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
cnn_train.py:44: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg..., units=150)`
  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
cnn_train.py:47: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=4)`
  model.add(Dense(output_dim=4, activation='sigmoid'))
Found 42 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 12 images belonging to 4 classes.
cnn_train.py:83: UserWarning: The semantics of the Keras 2 argument `steps_per_epoch` is not the same as the Keras 1 argument `samples_per_epoch`. `steps_per_epoch` is the number of batches to draw from the generator at each epoch. Basically steps_per_epoch = samples_per_epoch/batch_size. Similarly `nb_val_samples`->`validation_steps` and `val_samples`->`steps` arguments have changed. Update your method calls accordingly.
  nb_val_samples=320)
cnn_train.py:83: UserWarning: Update your `fit_generator` call to the Keras 2 API: `fit_generator(<keras.pre..., validation_data=<keras.pre..., steps_per_epoch=195, epochs=10, validation_steps=320)`
  nb_val_samples=320)
Epoch 1/10
2018-03-14 21:24:47.253618: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2018-03-14 21:24:47.757122: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.493
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.31GiB
2018-03-14 21:24:47.761770: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-03-14 21:24:50.602239: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:378] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7101 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7003 (compatibility version 7000).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
2018-03-14 21:24:50.612332: F C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You have cuDNN 7.1 installed, which is not compatible. Install cuDNN 7.0.

Comment: Thank you very much,It solved the problem