# CuDNN library compatibility error after loading model weights

Tags: tensorflow, magenta

I am trying to load NSynth weights and I am using tf version 1.7.0

```py
from magenta.models.nsynth import utils
from magenta.models.nsynth.wavenet import fastgen

def wavenet_encode(file_path):

 # Load the model weights.
 checkpoint_path = './wavenet-ckpt/model.ckpt-200000'

 # Load and downsample the audio.
 neural_sample_rate = 16000
 audio = utils.load_audio(file_path, 
                          sample_length=400000, 
                          sr=neural_sample_rate)

 encoding = fastgen.encode(audio, checkpoint_path, len(audio))

 # Reshape to a single sound.
 return encoding.reshape((-1, 16))

# An array of n * 16 frames. 
wavenet_z_data = wavenet_encode(file_path)
```

I get the following error:

> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:396] Loaded runtime CuDNN
>   library: 7103 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled
>   with 7005 (compatibility version 7000).  If using a binary install,
>   upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make
>   sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version
>   specified during compile configuration.

What should I do and, which version of tf should I install, and exactly which CUDA version do I need?

Answer (score 16):

As the error says, the Tensorflow version you are using is compiled for CuDNN 7.0.5 while your system has CuDNN 7.1.3 installed.

As the error also suggests, you can solve this problem:

- Either by installing CuDNN 7.0.5 (follow instructions here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn);
- Or by compiling Tensorflow yourself for your system (follow instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).

Comment: Instead of recompiling TensorFlow, even downgrading it works. I did this `pip install -U tensorflow==1.9.0` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

At the env:

```
ubuntu16.04   
cuda9.0   
cudnn7.0  
tensorflow 1.11.0  
python 3.5
```

I try to train the object detection with tensorflow, I meet this problem:

```
2018-10-18 21:31:36.796017: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:343] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

it's because the tensorflow version is higher;

I use `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0 --user` to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. I have (1) the same error (with a different ersion), (2) upgrading cuDNN to 7.4.x does not work, (3) 7.2.1 is only for CUDA 9.2, (4) I do not want to mess with rebuild the package myself and (5) nightly version does not help. Your solution is the one that I overlooked twice before trying it but it actually works !

Answer (score 1):

[benjaminplanche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960236/5542725) clearly answers the question. I would like to add a bit and I hope you would find it helpful.

For installing cuDNN, [**cudnnenv**](https://github.com/unnonouno/cudnnenv.git) is very convenient.

**[Cudnnenv](https://github.com/unnonouno/cudnnenv.git)** is like a manager that can manage various versions of cuDNN.
Installing cudnnenv is easy using pip:

```
pip install cudnnenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the version of `cudnn` that `tensorflow` is compiled with:

```
sudo apt install libcudnn7-dev=7.0.5.15-1+cuda<x> libcudnn7=7.0.5.15-1+cuda<x>
```

`<x>` symbol must be replaced with `cuda` version you have e.g. for `cuda` version `9.0` replace it with `9.0`.

Later freeze the version in apt that would not automatically update:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev
```

Comment: Mine was the other way around; TF was somehow compiled with the newer version. Since the default from Nvidia seems to be downloadable .deb files, no alternate versions were known to apt. So, I needed to download the newer .deb files from Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Tensorflow Nightly solved the problem for me:

`pip3 install tf-nightly-gpu`

Answer (score 0):

I removed:

```
  cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
  cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
  cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
  cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
  cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
  cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
  cudnn64_8.dll
```

from

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\~orch\lib
```

and

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib
```

I think tensorflow automatically loads these dlls if they exit.

**I'm not sure if this causes other issues!**