# cannot train Keras convolution network on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I can train a Keras network with `Dense` layer using `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist` dataset.  However, when I tried to train a convolutional network, I got an error.

Here is some part of the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

model = keras.Sequential([
        Convolution2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(16, activation='relu'),
        Dense(10, activation='softmax')    
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
```

and its error when I tried to fit.

> UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above.     [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}} =
>   Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1],
>   padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/TFOptimizer/gradients/conv2d/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer,
>   conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)]]    [[{{node
>   loss/dense_1_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2/_69}}
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_112_l...t/Switch_2",
>   tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I have `cudnn64_7.dll` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin` and the `PATH` is already contain that folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960236/6081433) would solve your problem, its because the cnDNN version you installed is not compatible with the cuDNN version that compiled in tensorflow.

Comment: I am using TensorFlow GPU version 1.12.0  CUDA 9.0.  I copied a new CUDNN library and its works.  Thank you.